# How can I install a plugin using jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

### Problem Statement

I am using Jenkins for CI/CD automation.  I installed the *[GitHub Pull Request Builder](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ghprb/)* through Jenkin's Plugin Manager.

[image: plugin manager]

However I cannot figure out how to do this with a Jenkins Pipeline

### Attempts/Documentation

I have skimmed through this exhaustive list of [pipeline steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/) and [declarative documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) but cannot find any documentation on how to accomplish this?

Comment: You're only getting downvote because you failed to style your post and didn't provide any examples of what you tried.  However, this is an excellent post because its novel.  In other words to has never been asked before!  I posted an answer, but I will format your question and provide more detail in my answer.  Also in the future please specific the Jenkins version you are using

Answer (score 1):

### Installing Plugin via Jenkinsfile

Firstly, I would question why exactly you want to do this.  This is a fairly odd requirement that I have not seen in my 10 years of Jenkins & Hudson experience.  With that said, anything that can be done in the Jenkins web interface, and a billion other things that cannot, can be done in either a Pipeline or in the Script Console because these two constructs have access to the entire SDK.

```
node {

    // 'ghprb' is this plugins short name value
    GITHUB_PULL_REQUEST_BUILDER = 'ghprb'
    for (plugin in [GITHUB_PULL_REQUEST_BUILDER]) {
        e = Hudson.instance.updateCenter.getPlugin(plugin).deploy().get().getError()
        if (e != null)
            println e.message
    }
}
```

### Security

Anything you see on the Jenkins GUI can be done in the script console or a pipeline via the Jenkins SDK.  Jenkins has implemented a Sandbox to prevent nefarious actors from executing malicious scripts.  Your requirement must use the Jenkins/Hudson SDK and therefore you have two options:

- Disable the [Sandbox](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/#sandbox) for this pipeline
- [Authorize](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/#script-approval) the scripts and/or methods being used

If you try and run the aforementioned script without solving these security constraints the following exception will be thrown:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method jenkins.model.Jenkins getUpdateCenter
```

#### Sandbox

To disable the Sandbox simply uncheck the "Use Groovy Sandbox" checkbox. This is the easiest solution.
[image: sandbox]

#### Script Approval

If your administrator does not authorize you to outright disable the Sandbox for that job then you can approve the method signatures used in your script or approve the script itself.

The following message signatures would need to be approved for this script

```
staticMethod hudson.model.Hudson getInstance
method jenkins.model.Jenkins getUpdateCenter
method hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin deploy
method java.util.concurrent.Future get
method hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterJob getError
```

### Additional Information

Most likely the plugin will not be available until a restart has occurred.  You can automate a restart a variety of ways. You can hit the following endpoints

- http://<jenkins.server>/restart
- http://<jenkins.server>/safeRestart

You could invoke the jenkins-cli.jar tool.  If you're feeling exceptionally risky you could even do something like `Jenkins.instance.restart()`

Note: don't use the SDK to restart unless you really know what you're doing